# Ajax Form Submission : no reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I need to do an ajax form submission. I have for options as answer to a question. When an option is selected i need to submit the form without reloading the page. The following is my code . Can someone tell me a solution.

I have tried alert inside the ajax function (not working) and before ajax function (working).

My code:

```js
function submit_answer(n) {
  var mark;
  var quiz_id = $('#quiz_id').val();
  var option = $('#radio' + n).val();
  var answer = $('#answer').val();
  var StateId = 0;

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'submit_test',
    data: {
      quiz_id: quiz_id,
      option: option,
      StateId: StateId,
      mark: mark
    },
    success: function(html) {
      alert(html);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="btn btn-info" id="rad5" align="left" onclick="submit_answer(5);" style="width:auto;">
  <input type="radio" name="option" style="display:none; visibility:hidden; opacity:0;" id="radio5" value="<?php echo $quiz['quiz_opt1'];?>" />
  <label for="radio5">
            <h3><?php echo $quiz['quiz_opt1'];?></h3>
        </label>
</div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="btn btn-info" id="rad6" align="left" onclick="submit_answer(6);" style="width:auto;">
  <input type="radio" name="option" style="display:none; visibility:hidden; opacity:0;" id="radio6" value="<?php echo $quiz['quiz_opt2'];?>" />
  <label for="radio6">
            <h3><?php echo $quiz['quiz_opt2'];?></h3>
        </label>
</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<div class="btn btn-info" id="rad7" align="left" onclick="submit_answer(7);" style="width:auto;">
  <input type="radio" name="option" style="display:none; visibility:hidden; opacity:0;" id="radio7" value="<?php echo $quiz['quiz_opt3'];?>" />
  <label for="radio7">
            <h3><?php echo $quiz['quiz_opt3'];?></h3>
        </label>
</div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;
<div class="btn btn-info" id="rad8" align="left" onclick="submit_answer(8);" style="width:auto;">
  <input type="radio" name="option" style="display:none; visibility:hidden; opacity:0;" id="radio8" value="<?php echo $quiz['quiz_opt4'];?>" />
  <label for="radio8">
            <h3><?php echo $quiz['quiz_opt4'];?></h3>
        </label>
</div>
```

Comment: You are not calling `submit_answer()` anywhere in your provided code?

Comment: I am sorry . Iam providing the edited code.PLease check the current code

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Can you check your console(Developer Options) in google chrome and tell me the exact error?

Comment: I would use jQuery now you have it: `$(".btn").on("click",function() {  $.post("submit_test",{
      quiz_id: $('#quiz_id').val(),
      option: $(this).find("[name=option"]).val(),
      StateId: StateId,
      mark: mark
    },function(result)  {.....});`

Comment: no no console errors. The form is now geting submitted but sometimes it is not getting submitted. then the console shows error which means  no $_POST value obtained at the controller

Answer (score 0):

i have just copied the code from your question, it worked for me without any interruption

Answer (score 0):

Is that code inside a form?. 
Well, if that's the case, there's the problem. Because the form has submition by default.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I misunderstood the question, your code seems to work correctly.